# Wifi problems Mac OS X 10.8.2 MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi

There are hundreds of threads regarding Mac OS X 10.8.2 wifi problems, but no thread is describing exactly my issue.

I have a MacBook Pro 2011 with OS X 10.8.2. Since around two months I have trouble with my wifi connection.

After booting the Mac, wifi is working as usual. Connecting automatically and everything. Without any notice it stops working from one moment to another. Sometimes two minutes, sometimes an hour, but always at some point the wifi stops working.

The system stops showing other networks within my area and only shows my network. Disabling and enabling wifi shows me the "wifi enabled" icon without a connection, but looking into the network preferences clearly states that the wifi is disabled. In addition I am not able to enable the wifi in the network preferences.

Things I have tried so far:

- Reinstalling the system (Time Machine Backup)
- PREM Reset (can't count how often)
- SMC Reset
- Keychain - deleting all wifi connections and information

I have the Checkpoint Endpoint Client E75 installed. It makes no difference if I use it or not. In addition I have the problem with every access point. I tried public hotspots, my companies wifi (Cisco hardware) and home network. Don't believe this is related to the protocol used by the router.

Comment: Have you run /System/Library/CoreServices/Wi-Fi Diagnostics and seen if you can capture a set of logs and send it to Apple for diagnostics? Are there messages in your console app about WiFi that might narrow down what is happening. Since this is repeatable, you should be able to pinpoint the messages that arrive each time it fails you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this seems to be a hardware issue. I had the chance to take the wifi module from an unused MBP at work. Now everything works fine.

Thank you for all suggestions and your help. Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If this is in your home, do you have an older microwave oven nearby? Or a 2.4GHz cordless phone? Baby monitor? Anything else "wireless" (that's not a wireless router/access point)?

Have you tried changing the channel of the wireless on the router? Many newer routers will do a "site survey" and indicate an unused wireless channel.

I have had similar problems with wireless in the past and solved it by changing the wireless channel.

Comment: As I stated above, this is happening everywhere. At the office, home, in cafes etc.. I believe this is not related to external sources.

Comment: What happens if you put the notebook near your router at home? Does it drop the connection?

Comment: Unfortunately no difference.

Comment: Did the problems start occurring when you installed the Checkpoint software? It shouldn't be related, but...

Comment: I had the Checkpoint client installed for about 6 months. So I don't believe it is related to this.

Comment: I've got nothing else. Take it to the Apple Store or your local Apple authorized repair depot for proper diagnostics.

Answer (score 2):

NEW: As commented by David, it is a hardware issue. My MB Pro came back from the shop with a new wireless card. Problem solved.

I am having the exact same problem suddenly. The only solution that works is using an ethernet connection.

I have tried using my iPhone via USB as my hotspot and that doesn't even work.

Everything you stated, I am seeing.

A question, did you recently install the firmware update for the battery issue?? That is the only change on my computer in the last couple of days. I have no idea if it is connected, but just seems like a possible cause.

Kaleb

Comment: I try to keep my Mac as updated as possible with the hope this fixes it at some point. So... yep, have done that. Good to hear I am not the only one.

Comment: I have run Apple's hardware test and kept receiving an error. I taking it to get fixed. I will let you know what they do and hope that it fixes it!

Comment: I spend last weekend to exchange the wifi card. Found an unused MBP at work and just changed the card. Seems like a hardware problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing Location, which is essentially a pool of the networks you regularly access. Mine apparently became corrupted after a recent update so I went through the gauntlet of "fixes" - many mentioned above - to no avail. A colleague who used to be an Apple Genius (still is in my book!) showed me the following:

- Open System Preferences
- Select Network
- Highlight Wi-Fi (or whatever your wireless n/w is called)
- Click the lock in the lower left corner to allow edits
- Select Edit Locations from Location pull-down menu in top-center
- Create any new Location - I called mine Test until the fix was confirmed
- Apply changes
- Confirm n/w connectivity - if good, delete problematic Location

Like most of the other suggestions out there, this likely won't help everyone, but for me it was instantaneous.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't fix my problem. But thanks for your reply. Any idea is welcome!